# how to debug django custom management commands in pycharm

Tags: django, debugging, pycharm

I am not able to add command-line arguments in edit configuration. I cannot see **Additional options** in the edit configuration which is mentioned in the docs.

Here is the step I have followed:

1. Run > Edit Configurations...
2. Click green + (plus sign)
3. In the drop-down menu, choose Django Server.
4. Check "Custom run command" and enter your command (the part that goes after manage.py in the console.
   Make sure "Port" and "Host" are empty. If not—make them empty.
   5."Apply" and "Close"

but my query is how to pass command-line arguments in the debugger?

Here is my script:

```
python manage.py insert -n  "subhanshu" -tz " Africa/Abidjan"  --activityperiod '[{"starttime":"24/11/1995-11:00PM"}]'
```

[image: Here is the screenshot of my configuration]

Comment: I don’t think you want to run a *Django server*, try a normal Python command.

Comment: I have tried it but it is not working @deceze

Comment: Could you please clarify what doesn't work with pure Python run configuration exactly?